# How to insert the content of a file into another file (if regexp) in perl/shell

Tags: regex, perl, shell, insert, paste

```
File1 Contents:

line1-file1      "1" 
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3" 
line4-file1      "4" 

File2 Contents:

line1-file2     "25"  
line2-file2     "24"  
Pointer-file2   "23"  
line4-file2     "22" 
line5-file2     "21"
```

After the execution of perl/shell script,

```
File 2 content should become

line1-file2     "25"  
line2-file2     "24"  
Pointer-file2   "23" 
line1-file1      "1" 
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3" 
line4-file1      "4"  
line4-file2     "22" 
line5-file2     "21"
```

i.e  Paste the contents of file 1 in file 2 after that  "Pointer" containing  line.

Thanks

Comment: Also asked at [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32908/4667)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a crosspost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the **`r`** command in `sed` to append text file:

```
$ sed -i '/Pointer-file2/r file1' file2

$ cat file2
line1-file2     "25"
line2-file2     "24"
Pointer-file2   "23"
line1-file1      "1"
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3"
line4-file1      "4"
line4-file2     "22"
line5-file2     "21"
```

---

Use the **`r`** command in `ed` to insert text file:

```
$ echo -e '/Pointer/-1r file1\n%w' | ed -s file2

$ cat file2
line1-file2     "25"
line2-file2     "24"
line1-file1      "1"
line2-file1      "2"
line3-file1      "3"
line4-file1      "4"
Pointer-file2   "23"
line4-file2     "22"
line5-file2     "21"
```

Comment: Sir, How to do the same if we want to paste before that "pointer" containing line

Comment: @user1228191 Actually, it's **`r`**, the slash belongs to **`/pattern/`**

Comment: yes kev, that was a typo error!! Is there anything like `r` command to paste it before that **pointer** containing line

Comment: How would one modify this such that the file is inserted before every occurrence of Pointer in file2?

Answer (score 4):

I'd [use Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html).  Roughly,

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @a, 'Tie::File', 'File2' or die;
tie my @b, 'Tie::File', 'File1' or die;
for (0..$#a) {
  if (/^Pointer-file2/) {
    splice @a, $_, 0, @b;
    last
  }
}
```

It's longer than that use of sed, but it should also be easier to see how you'd alter this for slightly different tasks.