# Using sed to insert file content

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to insert a file content before a given pattern

Here is my code:

```
sed -i "" "/pattern/ {
i\\ 
r $scriptPath/adapters/default/permissions.xml"
}" "$manifestFile"
```

It adds the path instead of the content of the file.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to insert text *before* a pattern, you need to swap the pattern space into the hold space before reading in the file. For example:

```
sed "/pattern/ {
         h
         r $scriptPath/adapters/default/permissions.xml
         g
         N
     }" "$manifestFile"
```

Comment: The script has to be double quoted, otherwise $scriptPath won't be expanded. Could you please explain why is N needed at the end?

Comment: @hipe The r command only queues the read for insertion into the output stream. It doesn't actually read anything until the end of the cycle or when the next line is read. Without N the file wouldn't be inserted until after the pattern space was printed, making it function as an append rather than an insert. It's *very* non-intuitive.

Comment: Seems sed is very picky with the 'r' command. According to http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq5_008.html: "Any additional characters before or after the filename are interpreted as part of the filename."

I tried `r someFile.txt # insert content of ...` and it failed silently.

Comment: This works fine as long as `pattern` is _not_ on the last line.

Comment: Hi, Todd and @vscharf, I found "h" & "g" are ommitable. I wrote this one-liner( https://stackoverflow.com/a/56182135/26736 ). Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Just remove `i\\`.

Example:

```
$ cat 1.txt
abc
pattern
def

$ echo hello > 2.txt

$ sed -i '/pattern/r 2.txt' 1.txt

$ cat 1.txt
abc
pattern
hello
def
```

Comment: It inserts after the pattern. How to insert the content before it ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried Todd's answer and it works great,

but I found "h" & "g" commands are ommitable.

Thanks to [this faq](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq5_008.html) (found from @vscharf's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content#comment35282910_11246712)), Todd's answer can be this one liner.

```
sed -i -e "/pattern/ {r $file" -e 'N}' $manifestFile
```

**Edit:**
If you need here-doc version, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47582028/trying-to-write-a-heredoc-into-an-existing-file-using-sed-in-bash#comment98990264_47584538).

Comment: this doesn't work if the match is on the last line or if  consecutive lines should match...

Answer (score 1):

I got something like this using awk. Looks ugly but did the trick in my test:

command:

```
cat test.txt | awk '
/pattern/ {
    line = $0;
    while ((getline < "insert.txt") > 0) {print};
    print line;
    next
}
{print}'
```

test.txt:

```
$ cat test.txt
some stuff
pattern
some other stuff
```

insert.txt:

```
$ cat insert.txt
this is inserted file
this is inserted file
```

output:

```
some stuff
this is inserted file
this is inserted file
pattern
some other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeGnome's solution don't work, if the pattern is on the last line..
So I used 3 commands.

```
sed -i '/pattern/ i\
        INSERTION_MARKER
        ' $manifestFile
sed -i '/INSERTION_MARKER/r $scriptPath/adapters/default/permissions.xml' $manifestFile
sed -i 's/INSERTION_MARKER//' $manifestFile
```

Comment: i found it most straightforward to use vim for this: `vim "$fileToEdit" <<< ':$-1 r'"$fileToInsert"$'\n:wq'`