# Add text to specific text line

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i'm kinda new to linux programing, and I've searched everywere, and i don't find any answer for my question, i have a file lets call it, config.txt/.ini;
My question is: Is there anyway with a script, to find in the file some text and if it finds the search text do something;

---

For exemple:

- Search for: 'my/text/mytext'
- And add: ';' to the begin of the line.
- or even delete the line.

Comment: If you're searching for "centos programming" you aren't going to get very far. You either want a bash script or a way to do this in a real scripting language like python/perl/tcl.

Comment: It's not like only centos programing, is more like unix/linux general programing.

Comment: Then tag it as shell scripting, not spam with random linux distributions tags. Thank you.

Comment: [95% duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243102/using-sed-to-insert-file-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered looking at tools such as:

- `awk`
- `sed`
- `perl`
- `python`

which all can do this fairly easily.

Awk is probably the slimmest (and thus fastest) of these:

```
awk '{sub(/root/, "yoda"); print}'
```

will substitute the first match for regexp `root` with the string `yoda` on each line.

Comment: And to delete the line what could it be like?

Comment: Read the `awk` manual. That is ALL in there. Put a filter before the `{`

Comment: I would add `sed` to the list

Comment: Well i tried sed and awk, but awk gives me some wierd error, and sed just makes that file empty, i want some script that does something like this:
`sed 's/addons\/mani_admin_plugin\/bin\/sourcemod_mm/ /' addons/metamod/metaplugins.ini > addons/metamod/metaplugins.ini`

With this i mean it to search for the string "addons/mani_admin_plugin/bin/sourcemod_mm", and remove it or replace it with a "space" (empty character).

Comment: Just don't *overwrite* the file the very moment you want to read from it. Use a temporary file, or the `-i` (inplace) switch.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is vague, and you didn't define what kind of script, and because I'm currently learning Python, I took the time to write a python script to remove lines in foo.txt that contain "mytext". Yes, it is possible. There are countless other ways to do it as well.

```
import re

# Open the file and read all the lines into an array
f = open("foo.txt", "r")
lines = []; 
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
f.close()

# Write all the lines back that don't match our criteria for removal
f = open("foo.txt", "w")
for line in lines:
    if re.search("mytext", line) == None:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: I think it's right this, so it will only remove the lines with "mytext" on them right?

Comment: Yep. It will read all the lines in, and open the file with "w", which will delete anything inside it already, and then write out all the lines that don't contain "mytext".

Comment: Hum ok i got it, but it gives me this errors relatives to the "f = open(..."

`
 line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 line 21: ` f = open("plugins.ini", "r");'
`

Comment: Why did you put a ' at the end?