# Insert specific lines from file before first occurrence of pattern using Sed

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

I want to insert a range of lines from a file, say something like `210,221r` before the first occurrence of a pattern in a bunch of other files.

As I am clearly not a GNU sed expert, I cannot figure how to do this.

I tried

```
sed '0,/pattern/{210,221r file
}' bunch_of_files
```

But apparently `file` is read from line 210 to EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/(FIND_ME)/PUT_BEFORE\1/' test.text
```

- `-r` [enables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165589/replace-regex-capture-group-content-using-sed) extendend regular expressions
- the string you are looking for ("FIND_ME") is inside parentheses, which creates a capture group
- `\1` puts the captured text into the replacement.

About your second question: You can read the replacement from a file like this*:

```
sed -r 's/(FIND_ME)/`cat REPLACEMENT.TXT`\1/' test.text
```

If replace special characters inside `REPLACEMENT.TXT` beforehand with `sed` you are golden.

*= this depends on your terminal emulator. It works in bash.

Comment: My problem is that PUT_BEFORE is several lines long and contains lots of special characters that would need to be escaped, that's why I want to read it from a file it is already in. I think I could create a temp file containing only these lines and read it, but I'd like to know if reading ranges is possible with GNU sed.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful but I've just found an answer that spares the additional cost of calling `cat` or another instance of `sed`. I will post it below but however it does not solve the problem of reading *specific* lines of a file yet.

Answer (score 0):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246712/4328188 CodeGnome gave some "sed black magic" :

> In order to insert text before a pattern, you need to swap the pattern space into the hold space before reading in the file. For example:
>
> ```
> sed '/pattern/ {
>      h
>      r file
>      g
>      N
>  }' in
> ```

However, to read *specific* lines from `file`, one may have to use a two-calls solution similar to dummy's answer. I'd enjoy knowing of a one-call solution if it is possible though.