# Insert text from file before pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I have two files(s.txt,d.txt), and want to insert s.txt into d.txt before the line containing 'hello'. 
I use

```
sed '/hello/i/r s.txt' d.txt
```

Comment: See: [Using sed to insert file content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11243102/3776858)

Comment: But this command cannot work. it treat the 'r s.txt' as a string and insert this string before the line containing 'hello'

Comment: Use this with GNU sed: `sed -e '/hello/{h;r s.txt' -e 'g;N}' d.txt`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!